# Excel - SUM and COUNTIFS

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I need to do a SUM in a row where there are some cells with "AL" and some cells with "HD".

The formula I have is
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B4:AF4,{"AL","HD"}))
but it assign 1 to both options.

I would like to do a sum assigning 1 to "AL" and 0.5 to "HD"

Is it possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B4:AF4="AL")+((B4:AF4="HD")*.5))
```

Or if you want to stick with COUNTIFS, double count the `AL` and divided the result by 2:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(B4:AF4,{"AL","AL","HD"}))/2
```